# Mirror API how to insert contact with optional properties?

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

php hack here, working with the [php quick start](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/php) project. Up to this point I've been using the basic contact added by default. I'm able to share a photo with that contact and post the photo along with the latitude/longitude to Wordpress, it's working great.

However, I would like to insert a contact with a few of the optional properties, but am having a hard time figuring out the best way to go about doing that. I would like to add:

1. [acceptCommands[].type](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts/insert#acceptCommands.type) property with a value of `TAKE_A_NOTE`
2. [sharingFeatures[]](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts/insert#sharingFeatures) with a value of `ADD_CAPTION`

It doesn't look like the [insert_contact](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-php/blob/master/mirror-client.php#L125) function is setup for those options. Do I need to modify that function to pass in the additional properties I want? I'm a little confused on the format needed for [acceptCommands[].type](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts/insert#acceptCommands.type). It says `string` is required but when I look at the output at the top of [/glass/v1/reference/contacts](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts) - it looks like an array.

Can someone please help to get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have downloaded the latest google-api-php-client (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client appears to be the authoritative source now). There was a change intoduced with XE8 that was incorporated into version 0.6.6 which enabled sharingFeatures - 0.6.6 is the minimum version necessary for these features, and it is part of the QuickStart example. (Note that there have been some changes in the 1.0 client, but they are mostly naming changes. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration for details about the changes.)

I'm not quite sure what you're asking about acceptCommands. In PHP terms, this should be an array of arrays. (Or a numeric based array, each consisting of associative arrays mapping from a string (currently the value "type") to a string (either the strings "TAKE_A_NOTE" or "POST_AN_UPDATE").

I haven't tested this, but if you wanted your contact to work with both voice commands (for example), you should be able to use code something like this:

```
$acceptCommands =
    array(
          array("type" => "TAKE_A_NOTE"),
          array("type" => "POST_AN_UPDATE")
          );
$contact->setAcceptCommands( $acceptCommands );
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up about google-api-php-client, I had no idea that existed. That is a bummer as I've been working with the quick start project provided by Google. Not sure I have the chops to upgrade that!

Comment: The QuickStart project was also updated with the latest version of google-api-php-client. So make sure you have the most recent QuickStart.

Comment: The "Download on GitHub" link on this page: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/php links to a repo that uses 0.6.6. Is that the most current?

Comment: The migration guide link is killer, thanks for all of your help